# Caching objects for later reuse to avoid persistence to recreate them

Tags: java, object, caching

I have this idea of caching objects that have been created for a slight performance gain. The types of objects I'm thinking of is stuff like Player objects in a game. I think it could be beneficial to have a cached copy of the player ready to avoid any io/persistence.

The idea sounds great however I have some issues(?) I guess with that idea. The player data is stored on a SQL database. So if I was to make a change to the database, the cached copy on the server would be different. I could run a task to check objects are up-to-date but then there would be no point in the initial idea.

Could I have some advice on what I should do?

Comment: As you mentioned, the access to the database overweighs the benefit of storing the player in a variable. But maybe you need to overthink your game again, if it really needs to store the player in the database

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I do need to store data in into a database because it's shared data (e.g. used by my website and another application) so a database is the best solution for that. My goal really is to keep the game server light? If that makes sense and to remove as much latency as I can.

Comment: As Jeff Atwood [said](https://mobile.twitter.com/codinghorror/status/506010907021828096?lang=en), "There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors." This is one of the trickiest aspects of software development. You have to invalidate cached items somehow, either after a certain amount of time or when you update the master data.

Comment: I honestly think this is too broad. Whole books, heck PhD thesis's are written about such topic.

Comment: caching makes sense - happens everywhere. Make sure you can access your DB only via 'module' which retrieves and caches, but also invalidates when you write. You will always find a way to break it. Make sure you use proper cache with eviction policies, rather than ever growing `HashMap`.

Comment: @EdCottrell thanks, the invalidation method was great! I've decided to create an independent module that notifies me of changes in the master data. Listening for these triggers I think is much "lighter" than performing the IO all the time I think.